# substring algorithm

Tags: algorithm, string, search, substring

Can anyone point to best algorithm for substring search in another string?
or search for a char array in another char array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best from what point of view? [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth-Morris-Pratt_algorithm) is a good one. You can find more of them discussed on [the Wikipedia entry for string searching algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what types of searching you are doing. Specific substring over a specific string? Specific substring over many different strings? Many different substrings over a specific string?

[Here's a popular algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%2dMoore_string_search_algorithm) for a specific substring over many different strings.

Answer (score 1):

Boyer-Moore algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer–Moore_string_search_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

[This strstr() implementation](http://sources.redhat.com/ml/libc-alpha/2006-07/txt00009.txt) seems pretty slick.

Comment: It is strstr.c for alpha. Which algorithm it uses? Which algorithm is used in x86 (or _64) for strstr?